# Theme doesn't display image correctly on the first load

Tags: html, css, tumblr

The problem is still unsolved and I don't know why . However ; change another theme can fix it 
. 
.......................................

I have a problem about the theme of tumblr . It hasn't been "working" since the first time . It doesn't mean it don't work . **It only works after I refresh the page .**

**The first time I load the page ; most of the elements (images) of the content are un-styled ; they overlaps each others and that's annoying**

Here is the theme

http://tinypaste.com/fa31b3

If I'm not wrong ; this's responsible for the images .

```
 .entry img { 
{block:IndexPage}
width: {block:IfNot2Columns}240px{/block:IfNot2Columns}{block:If2Columns}500px{/block:If2Columns}; 
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}
width:500px;
{/block:PermalinkPage}
}
```

Can you guys help me out . Any ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that browsers caches you styles with previous styles for images, and because of it browsers have no actual rules(have only previuos styles) for your images.

I have more readable and flexible solution for you, which will work without exceptions:

**Tumblr markup:**

```
<body class="
{block:IndexPage}
    index-page
    {block:IfNot2Columns}not-twocolumns{/block:IfNot2Columns}
    {block:If2Columns}twocolumns{/block:If2Columns}
{/block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage} permalink-page{/block:PermalinkPage}
">
```

**CSS:**

```
.index-page.not-twocolumns .entry img {
    width: 240px;
}

.index-page.twocolumns .entry img {
    width: 500px;
}

.permalink-page .entry img {
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help ; man 

I don't fully understand your ideas ; but guess you're right ; since most of the images load sooner are correctly styled ;  while those late ones are overlapped by the others

I will try your solution and feedback later :D

Comment: I'm sorry ; it doesn't work :( And sorry again for late answer ; I got stuck by the exams

Recently I have changed an other theme and the problem was solved . 

Thank all of you for the support :)

Comment: @Tiana987642 have you remember, how do you solve your problem? have you small test case and solution for it or maybe just solution helpful for you? I'm asking just for people who meats the same problem as you

Comment: I just change another theme . Basically I test it on FF ; Chrome and Opera with the disk cache's cleared . I have a friend test it as well . 

It take time longer than usual to figure out what's wrong (which I need so much for the exam) so I change to another theme .

Answer (score 0):

have you waited long enough for the content on the page to load?

when i use facebook on my outdated laptop, the same thing happens to me but it fixes itself in about 30-40 seconds once everything is loaded.

Comment: Yes;man . The page is loaded completely . The images are fully loaded and overlapped on others ; not loaded partially . And only for the first visit ; next time when everything on the cache ; it works.

Comment: the thing is that in my (limited) experience, if something works on refresh, that is an indication that the problem isn't really in the code. because if you think about it, if a line of code is broken, why would i magically start working just by hitting refresh?

have you tried on different browsers/computers?

Comment: Yes; man . At least 2 of my friends have this trouble ; and we tested it on Firefox ; Opera and Chrome .

I can't figure out what's wrong :(

Comment: darn, i'm sorry i couldn't be of more assistance but that code snippet you've got up there looks right to me... nothing stands out in particular...

Comment: Ok ; man . I appreciate your help .
This problem is uncommon and pretty weird :(